# SQL Literal in JPA Hibernate Formula using TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, formula

For a JPA entity with a pseudo column defined using `@Formula`:

```
@Formula("TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateColA, dateColB)")
private Long duration;
```

Here `SECOND` is expected to be treated as a constant literal (with MySQL), however, in the generated JPQL, it is treated as a column name, just like `dateColA` and `dateColB`, like:

```
where ... TIMESTAMPDIFF(entity_.SECOND, entity_.dateColA, entity_.dateColB) ...
```

I wonder how to get the JPQL generated correctly for the `SECOND` literal?

Thanks

Comment: The answer in [SEPARATOR keyword not working properly in Hibernate Formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688660/group-concat-with-separator-is-not-working-properly-in-hibernate-formula) should help here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateColA, dateColB) in a mysql function

this in Java code:

```
@Formula("second_diff(dateColA, dateColB)")
private Long duration;
```

this to create the function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `second_diff`( dateColA date, dateColB date ) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
   DECLARE diff INT;
   SET diff =  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dateColA, dateColB);
   RETURN diff;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```