# Use DATE_ADD in Hibernate @Formula

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to use DATE_ADD (Mysql) function in a Hibernate Formula.

This is my field:

```
@Formula(value = "(SELECT DATE_ADD(v.dataAndata, INTERVAL v.minutiTrasportoAndata MINUTE) FROM VenditaB2B v WHERE v.id = id)")
private Date dataImbarco;
```

Unfortunately when Hibernate does the query it translates the query as:

```
(SELECT DATE_ADD(v.dataAndata, venditab2b0_.INTERVAL v.minutiTrasportoAndata venditab2b0_.MINUTE) FROM VenditaB2B v WHERE v.id = venditab2b0_.id) as formula5_
```

and of course it's wrong because it believes that MINUTE and INTERVAL are columns of my table VenditaB2B.
I tried with single and double quotes without luck.

There is a way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You will find an answer here: [SEPARATOR keyword not working properly in Hibernate Formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688660/separator-keyword-not-working-properly-in-hibernate-formula)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesnt support `DATE_ADD` syntax for MySQL. So you have to use native query

Ref : https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=982311&view=next

Comment: I know that is not supported. Infact I'm using my custom dialect where I added registerFunction("date_add_interval", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "DATE_ADD(?1,INTERVAL ?2 ?3)")); this function. But formula seems use native query. Infact date_add_interval is not recognized as valid function in @Formula.

Comment: The query in `@Formula` is already a native one.
However it seems some mysql constructs are not supported. Really not sure but maybe `@Formula` supports the keyword escape syntax like in `@Column` : `[INTERVAL] v.minuti [MINUTE]`.

Comment: Which MySQL dialect are you using?

Comment: I'm extending MySQL5InnoDBDialect