# Calculating age from birthdate with @Formula

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb

I'm trying to calculate the user's age from her birthdate, using `@Formula`.

According [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-calculations.html), I have tried this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public final class UserProfile {

   //this column is called BIRTHDATE in database
   private String birthdate;

    @Formula("(select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,BIRTHDATE,CURDATE()) from users)")
    private String age;

    //more things...

}
```

But I get an error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near
>   'userprofil0_.YEAR,userprofil0_.BIRTHDATE,CURDATE()) from users) as
>   formula0_0_ f' at line 1

If I execute that query in phpMyAdmin, it works properly.

Following [this](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-calculate-entity-attributes-formula/), I have also tried with:

```
@Formula("date_part('year', age(birthdate))")
private String age; //I tried with int instead of String, too
```

But I have this error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION
>   userprofile-service-db.date_part does not exist

This one does not work even in phpMyAdmin...

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I have just tried with:

```
@Formula("(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,BIRTHDATE,CURDATE()))")
private String age;
```

but is still not working. This is the query that Hibernate shows:

```
 select
        userprofil0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        userprofil0_.about_me as about_me2_1_0_,
        userprofil0_.birthdate as birthdat3_1_0_,
        userprofil0_.display_name as display_4_1_0_,
        userprofil0_.email as email5_1_0_,
        userprofil0_.profile_photo as profile_6_1_0_,
        (TIMESTAMPDIFF(userprofil0_.YEAR,
        userprofil0_.BIRTHDATE,
        CURDATE())) as formula0_0_ 
    from
        users userprofil0_ 
    where
        userprofil0_.id=?
```

It looks like Hibernate is taking `YEAR` as a column, but actually it is a reserved word. If I execute that query in phpMyAdmin replacing `userprofil0_.YEAR` with just `YEAR`, it works fine.

Comment: Hi! I updated my answer. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt was almost right, but you don't need `select` and `from` parts since column `BITHDATE` is in the same table:

```
@Formula("(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,BIRTHDATE,CURDATE()))")
private String age;
```

Also would be useful to turn on the logging of generated SQL query (in Hibernate it's done by setting property `show_sql` to `true`), to see the whole query.

**UPDATE**

As a workaround of the treating `YEAR` as a column name by Hibernate you can wrap call to `TIMESTAMPDIFF` in a custom MySQL function and call this function in Formula. Here is the SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475889/1252056) to a similar problem.

Another solution could be to write a custom dialect resolver, which will treat YEAR as a keyword: SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690804/1252056)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your solution. Check my edit. Looks like Hibernate is taking YEAR as a column of the table, but actually it is a reserved word

Comment: Have you tried to wrap `YEAR` in single quotes `'YEAR'` or in backticks ```YEAR```?

Comment: Yes, both. With single quotes, query crashes and with backquotes, it is taken as table column, too

Comment: Strange, cause according to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/thjanssen/df8a2c70b492a18d709661b96fb5b1b1/#file-author-java) backticks (`) should do the work

Comment: Thanks, I have created a function and now it works nice!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are making the age a string? I believe it should be an int shouldn't it?

Comment: Correct, int would make more sense, but in the OP question the age is a string, so I kept it the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try this formula to calculate the difference between current date and BIRTHDATE column stored in the database to get user age in year

```
@Formula("YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(BIRTHDATE)")
private int age;
```

Comment: This does not work. It returns the same value for all days of one year. But the age changes during the year.